# Access C# .dll in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dll, sqlclr

I have a DLL with a method that I want to access from SQL Server
When I run

```
create assembly ClassLibrary2
from 'D:\UtilityMethods.dll'
go
```

I get this error:

> Assembly 'UtilityMethods' references assembly 'teste, version=1.0.0.0,
>   culture=neutral, publickeytoken=429d4908cc20f9a0.', which is not
>   present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and
>   automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location
>   where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed
>   (reason: 2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)).
>   Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and
>   retry your request.

Inside `UtilityMethods.dll` there is a reference to `teste`.  However, the DLL works in console projects without the `teste` assembly present, so why does SQL Server need it and how can I get this to work?

Comment: Have you made sure that the folder D:\ is relative to the SQL Server machine, and not from where your Management Console is ?

Comment: @soamazing: I think that's your problem.  I'm pretty sure there are significant restrictions on the type of assembly you can reference directly from Sql Server.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx for an example.